# Is there a way to regenerate the secret used to access a Key Vault?

Tags: azure-keyvault

We have had ClientSecrets to access Key Vaults in our appsettings under source control for a long time. I am removing them from the checked in files, but I now need to regenerate them. I can't find any tutorials on how to do this. Can't find anything on the portal either. Is this not possible?

Comment: You can generate the client secret from azure portal>>go to active directory>>app registration>>click on the app which is r registered>> In the application screen, click Certificates & Secrets under manage and generate new client secret.

Answer (score 1):

Try with generating secrete from azure portal

**1)** Go to **active directory-->App registration**

[image]

**2)** Select the your app registration and click on the **Certificates and secrets**.

[image]

**3)** Click on **New Click Secrete**

[image]

**4)** Add the secret and click on the **Add**.

[image]

If you are facing any issue with generating or getting any error please  share the screen shot of messages.